# fetching images from mysql throw smarty

Tags: php, mysqli, smarty

i am new in smarty and i have a little problem that i cant fetch images for my posts. I store the images path in table ( images ) and the posts in table (posts):

my php code is

```
    $get_new_jobs=$mysqli->query("select id,numview,title,cat1,details,country,active from ads where country='".$country_en."' and active='1' order by id desc limit 4");
    $nums=$get_new_jobs->num_rows;
    while($row=$get_new_jobs->fetch_assoc()){

        $mm[]=$row;

    }

$smarty->assign('posts',$mm);
$smarty->assign('image',$the_images_name);
$smarty->display('posts.tpl');
```

and my images code is

```
$sql=mysqli->query("select adid,image,p from images where adid='".$row['id']."'");
$fet = $sql->fetch_assoc();
$the_images_name = $fet['image'];
```

and the tpl code is

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5">
{foreach from=$posts item=item}
<tr valign="top">
<td>        
{$image}
<br />
{$item.title}
</td>
</tr>        
{/foreach}
</table>
```

so how can i get each image for each post.

regards

Comment: first thing the {$image} should be like 
<img src="{$image}" />

And second do you have multiple images per post?

Comment: how can i insert the images query inside the posts loop dear ... this is what i nees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can fetch the image inside the loop and then can assign the image url to the index of the same array you are sending the post data

The Php part

```
$get_new_jobs=$mysqli->query("select id,numview,title,cat1,details,country,active from ads where country='".$country_en."' and active='1' order by id desc limit 4");
    $nums=$get_new_jobs->num_rows;
    while($row=$get_new_jobs->fetch_assoc())
    {

        $sql=mysqli->query("select adid,image,p from images where adid='".$row['id']."'");
        $fet = $sql->fetch_assoc();
        $the_images_name = $fet['image'];
        $row['image_url']= $the_images_name;
        $mm[]=$row;
     }

$smarty->assign('posts',$mm);
$smarty->display('posts.tpl');
```

The tpl part

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5">
{foreach from=$posts item=item}
<tr valign="top">
<td>        
<img src="{$item.image_url}">
<br />
{$item.title}
</td>
</tr>        
{/foreach}
</table>
```

Comment: @BbWay Always here to help :)